# Can't align text to bottom in scrollable column with TextFields [flutter]

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a form that takes input for multiple data and submits that data. But I'm having issues with the layout. I want the text `Don't have an account?` to be aligned at the bottom of the page. So I'm using `Spacer()` widget for that. And when I'm clicking on one of the field, the keyboard opens up and an `overflow` error occurs.

Turns out that I need to make my column scrollable to fix that error so I'm using `SingleChildScrollView` for that. But when I'm using the scroll view, I can't use the `Spacer` widget hence I'm not  able to align the `Don't have an account` text to the bottom. How can I have a scrollable column and the text aligned to bottom? I can't figure this out.

Here is my current code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 100,
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Field 1'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Field 2'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Field 3'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Field 4'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Field 5'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('SUBMIT'),
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              Text('Don\'t have an account?'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wrap the `column` with a `SingleChildScrollView` and remove the `spacer` widget andtry to add a sized box with a hight calculated with media query then wrap the text widget with an `positioned` widget with `bottom:0`, will this work? Try and share your comment

Comment: I was also thinking of using the dynamic height with `SizedBox` instead of `Spacer`, but do you think that's a good idea? Will that work in all the possible cases? And I don't think we need `Positioned` widget here as that must be inside a `Stack`.

Comment: Adding Dynamic height mostly will solve the issue here. As of now you you are assigning constant heights so even though you get the code to run properly now, it will failed with a smaller device.

Comment: Setting this text as the `BottomNavigationBar` works fine for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class test extends StatelessWidget {
  const test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 100,
                ),
                const TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Field 1'),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                const TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Field 2'),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                const TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Field 3'),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                const TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Field 4'),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                const TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Field 5'),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Text('SUBMIT'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        bottomSheet: const SizedBox(
          height: 30,
          child: Center(child: Text('Don\'t have an account?')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want the text to sit on the the keyboard

Comment: I'm not sure this will get the job done, It would be good if you could share more information here as well